# Need help using subString

Tags: java, substring

```
public class project5{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] storage = {"123457897", "123456","654654654"};
    int current;
    current = Integer.parseInt(storage[1].subString(1,5));
    System.out.println(current);
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to, as an exercise, just get the first 5 numbers in the first thing of the array and parse it as an integer and store it as the variable current. It gives me the error:

`test.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        current = Integer.parseInt(storage[1].subString(1,5));
                                             ^
  symbol:   method subString(int,int)
  location: class String
1 error`

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you see a method called `sub  S  tring`?

Comment: It's `substring()`, all lowercase.

Comment: Dude, are you writing your code in Notepad ? IDEs have code completion which should protect you from such mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

There is no `subString` method on the String class. There only is `substring` (all lowercase).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

For variable, class and method names casing matters.